# What is the plurality of the word "news"?

Tags: plural-forms, history

I thought the plurality could be not much of a matter because it has a letter "s" in the end but each news is counted as a news article or newspaper or so. But after reading this passage by Shakespeare, it made me think about how the plurality of the *concept* of news is treated in English (both historically and now):

> MACBETH
>
> LADY MACBETH: [to the SERVANT] What **is** your tiding**s**?
>
> (Modern translation by Sparknotes): What **news** do you bring?

It seems like "tidings" is "news," so it's either plural or singular (as a mass noun). It's really thought provoking and making me so curious what it actually means to say, "news".

Here's what I've come up so far:

- News is telling something that has happened.
- Or no, a news is a piece of such information.
- News can be broken up into units of what thing is conveying such a piece.

But I'm not sure I'm right. I need to share opinions.

So I want to ask you to define "news," and how it's treated in the language. Learners are fine too, as they can compare with their own language, giving me insights.

Comment: News is uncountable, like "information" or "advice". You can't count them so there is no plural.

Answer (score 3):

"News" is a "mass noun" that does not have a plural, sort of like "gravel" or "luggage". So, you can say:

> I have some news.
>
> The news is really bad. We lost the war and the king was killed. [Two facts, but still "the news is".]

You cannot say:

> Somebody told me a news today. [Even if it is just one piece of news.]

(Etymologically, "news" arose as the plural of "new", but it no longer is thought of that way.)

Comment: The term you're looking for is "uncountable". (not "mass noun")

Comment: I would have used a Macbeth reference:  "The news is really bad -- the trees are coming to get you."

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - Wikipedia and Merriam-Webster seem to think "mass noun" is a valid term for the concept. I think they're synonyms.

Comment: If news is always uncountable, why did Shakespeare use "tiding**s**", not just "tiding"? The extra 's' would seem redundant? Is it just because English is a living language and there's quirks like that?

Comment: @KimYuJin "Tidings" is still an uncountable/mass noun today.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - No, ["mass noun" is a perfectly valid term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun).

Comment: @MattCline My bad. It's just that "countable/uncountable" is used with learners, I guess "mass noun/count noun" is not as intuitive.